# tip3055/2N2222 coil steering

Tags: transistors, coil, magnet, electromagnet

i want to switch an electromagnet with a 2N2222 & TIP3055
switching should be triggered by a coil passing a magnet as optcal would be to slow

can anybody assist or give us some advice. we don't get it working[image]

Comment: Have you got an oscilloscope to measure the waveform on the base of the 2N2222? (Tip: use Q1, Q2, L1, BAT1, etc. on your diagrams so we can discuss them without confusion. Also, I would deduct marks from your work for lack of capitalisation and punctution.) You are missing the snubber diode on the coils so you may have destroyed the 3055.

Comment: Optical is nearly always faster than magnetic so I don't know where you learned that.

Comment: that's correct, i've added the diode as show içn the diagram below

Comment: You can add a freewheeling diode across the coil. Try searching on it.